# split pandas with no common values between splits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column `ID` as follows.

```
ID
1 
1
1
20
20
30
50
50
51
60
60
300
300
302
302
500
```

Is there any **automatic efficient** way I can split this into `n`,lets say `n=4` chunks such that

```
chunk-1:
ID
1
1
1
20
20

chunk-2:
ID
30
50
50
51

chunk-3:
ID
60
60
300
300

chunk-4:
ID
302
302
500
```

It should be noted that

1. size of each chunk may not be same.
2. There is no common values between any of the chunks.

I tried with simple `df_split = np.array_split(df, 4)` but **it does not fulfil condition 2 in the above 2 conditions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` to split data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,20,20,30,40,40,51,60,60,300,300,302,302,500]})
df_grouped = [subgroup for _, subgroup in df.groupby('id')]
```

If you want to gather this result as four groups,

```
df_grouped_new = [df_grouped[0], df_grouped[1], df_grouped[2], pd.concat(df_grouped[3:])]
```

Then

```
print(df_grouped_new[0])
>>> 
   id
0   1
1   1
2   1
```

```
print(df_grouped_new[1])
>>>
   id
3  20
4  20
```

```
print(df_grouped_new[2])
>>>
   id
5  30
```

```
print(df_grouped_new[3])
>>> 
     id
6    40
7    40
8    51
9    60
10   60
11  300
12  300
13  302
14  302
15  500
```